# Azure hosting setup for Node api, Reactjs, Python fast api and React Native

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, azure

I am new to Azure. I have the following applications that I need to host.

- Node Api v18 (backend)
- Reactjs (frontend)
- Python Fast Api (backend)
- React-Native (frontend)

I've been told to host the Reactjs on a storage account and have it connect to the Node Api on a virtual server. What settings/options would be best for the applications. Would I have the python running on its own virtual server?

Is it easy to delete/cancel these options if I make a mistake. Any risks?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the React Native application would be deployed to the platform specific app store.

Both the NodeJS and Python backends can be deployed to [Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview). This is a serverless container runtime service.

As for the ReactJS frontend, if you intend to leverage Server-Side Rendering (SSR), you should deploy this to [Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview) as well.

If it's a Single Page Application (SPA), then you could choose between [Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview) or [Static Website on Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).

Azure Static Web Apps has a few additional features compared to the static website approach. So this would be depend on your requirements.

Finally, to tie all these together, you should use [Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview) to ensure your app has a single point of entry. You can setup routes so that your frontend react application and backend all have the same domain name, allow you to setup cross region deployments (your host your application in different regions on your own), setup Web Application Firewall, etc.

Comment: Why not create a virtual machine to host the Nodejs and Reactjs together?

Comment: React Native application - how would be able to deploy onto the mobile for testing?

Comment: You could use a Virtual Machine as well, but it usually comes with a lot more maintenance overhead like OS updates, network security, etc. PaaS services like Container Apps or App Service do most of that for you, letting you focus just on your application. But if required, you could always take that route.

Comment: The [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) for React Native covers the steps required to run your application on a device.